# how to trigger same event from multiple device from one device

Tags: java, android, sockets

i am building app which will become server and other 3 or 5 phones become client. and from server i will send code for instruction all device click photo at same time. i am confusing how to do that..i have tcp/udp but it only connect 1 device but i want multiple device.

```
   class MyServer implements Runnable
{

    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream;
    String msg="";
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            serverSocket=new ServerSocket(9700);

            while (true)
            {
                socket=serverSocket.accept();
                dataInputStream=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                msg= dataInputStream.readUTF();

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public class Backgroundtask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    Socket socket;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String ip,msg;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        ip=strings[0];
        msg=strings[1];
        try {
            socket=new Socket(ip,9700);
            dataOutputStream=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(msg);
            dataOutputStream.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

i want when i am trigger instruction from server all device must follow at same time.

Comment: I would do that with Firebase Realtime Database. You can push a value to a base from one app and then base triggers all other apps subscribed to a specific topic.

Comment: i am also think that..but in firebase issue is timing  of reviving notification at same time. is there any thing in fireabse so we detect all msg recieve in devices